# Smooth Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms form a Baire space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $S$ be a closed surface equipped with an area form $\omega$. In Corollary 1.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06336.pdf), Asaoka and Irie demonstrated that Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms which have a dense set of periodic points in $S$ form a residual set in $\text{Ham}(S,\omega)$ (under the $C^{\infty}$-topology). The authors referred to this fact as the $C^{\infty}$ general density theorem. However, for the term 'density' to make sense, it seems necessary to assume that $\text{Ham}(S,\omega)$ is a Baire space. I haven't come across a paper where this is proven. Is this a well-known result among experts? I would greatly appreciate any insights.